# Creating an inset dropShadow on a container

Tags: apache-flex, containers, dropshadow

I am wondering how I could create a dropshadow on a container that would give the appearance that the container is lower than its parent.  Normally the dropshadow is applied primarily to the outside  of the right and lower sides.  What I want to achieve is a dropshadow to be applied to the inside of the  top and left sides.  The idea is to give the appearance that the container is embedded into its parent.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Easy as pie: you need the `inner` property: [DropShadowFilter#inner](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/filters/DropShadowFilter.html#inner)

Example:

```
<s:Rect width="100" height="100">
    <s:fill>
        <s:SolidColor color="0xff0000" />
    </s:fill>

    <s:filters>
        <s:DropShadowFilter inner="true" />
    </s:filters>
</s:Rect>
```

Comment: Just note that the RectangularDropShadow is more performant.  You can use the "angle" property to turn it to be within the top left corner rather than below the bottom right corner.  Also note you need to put it on top of whatever you're shadowing, rather than below (in MXML, this means you define the Rect first, then the shadow).

Comment: @Amy Thanks. Didn't know about that one. Do you perhaps know whether the performance difference will be noticeable on a regular PC/laptop? Or is RectangularDropShadow intended for mobile?

Comment: It probably depends on what else you're doing.  For instance, if you're doing a lot of them on alpha transparent objects, it's possible.

Comment: Great Guys, - I'm actually doing this in 3.5 but I came up with pretty much the same solution!

Muchos Appreciation!

Comment: @Beaker I still see a big fat zero and no green checkmark though.

Comment: Hi RIAstar,  how do I set the question to be 'answered' ?

Comment: You just click the checkmark. But I think you may need more reputation than you have to be able to do it (I reckon that's rather stupid, but that's how it appears to be). I'll give you a push.